# openstack: where does nova keep guest devices information in database?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, openstack, qemu, openstack-nova

This is `openstack` specific question.
I am using `openstack` of `Juno` version. I have `kvm/qemu` hypervisors with libvirt. I want to know where nova stores information related to my virtual instance's interface and disks. Does anybody know about it?

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in `nova` database's `instance_info_cache` and `block_device_mapping` tables.